# How to elegantly implement static singleton generics in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have some static classes bound to configuration files. Is there any better way so that I don’t have to write the GetValue method repeatedly every time?

```cs
    public class ApiPath 
    {
        private static readonly string Path = "Config/ApiPath.json";
        #region Get Config Method
        public static IConfiguration? Configuration { get; private set; }

        public static ConfigValue GetValue()
        {
            if (Configuration == null) Configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile(Path, true, true).Build();

            var model = new ConfigValue();
            Configuration.Bind(model);

            return model;
        }
        #endregion
        public string GetCookieAPi { get; set; }
        public string CheckCookieAPi{ get; set; }
    }
```

```cs
    public class ConfigValue
    {
        private static readonly string Path = "Config/Config.json";
        #region Get Config Method
        public static IConfiguration? Configuration { get; private set; }

        public static ConfigValue GetValue()
        {
            if (Configuration == null) Configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile(Path, true, true).Build();

            var model = new ConfigValue();
            Configuration.Bind(model);

            return model;
        }

        #endregion
        public string ServerIP { get; set; }
        public  string MongoDbStr {  get; set; }
        public int CookieIntervals { get; set; }

    }
```

I use inheritance or generics, but I always encounter problems with static member ownership.

Comment: Is there a special reason you do not want to use DI?

Comment: it's In non-server environments,I just want to implement a static global variable that binds to a JSON file......

Comment: ASP.NET and non-server environments - how does this fit together 

Comment: @PhonexAlica first, you don't need to do anything special, a static property setter or field is more than enough. If you want lazy initialization you can use `Lazy<T>`. Second, DI works on all types of applications and web apps are by definition servers. Static singletons are hard to test and mock

Answer (score 0):

In your case i would use static constructors (it will be automatically called once):

```
public class ConfigValue
{
    private static readonly string Path = "Config/Config.json";

    public static ConfigValue()
    {
        Instance = new ConfigValue();
        Configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile(Path, true, true).Build();           
        Configuration.Bind(Instance);
    }

    public static ConfigValue Instance {get; private set;}
    public static IConfiguration? Configuration { get; private set; }

    
    public string ServerIP { get; set; }
    public  string MongoDbStr {  get; set; }
    public int CookieIntervals { get; set; }

}
//usage
ConfigValue.Instance.CookieIntervals = 1
```